# Is there an easy/fast way to check linux compatibility of a .NETCore web app?

Tags: linux, .net-core, nuget

We have a .NETCore 3.1 web application and are planning to run it on linux.

The problem we are facing is we have to be 99% sure every feature works correctly, and do not have the capacity to do it manually.

Now we know from the top of our heads some packages and features which are windows dependent and won't work, but is there an easy way to tell about all the installed NuGet packages whether they are linux compatible or not (maybe from the dependencies of the package)?

*Excuse me if it is a stupid question or the answer is trivial, we could not think of any easy/fast method to check this.*